# Using MAYA 3D Model in a .Net application

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, xna, maya

If I want to render a 3D model created by Maya and do some animation with it in a .net application what should be my choice of platform - plain WPF or XNA?

Comment: Do you want to export an animation from Maya and just show a playback in the .NET application, or should the animation be created in the application?

Comment: animation would be created in maya and I want to replay it in the .net application with a certain degree of control, like changing perspective or camera, light etc.

Comment: I'm guessing XNA will be your best bet. What "export" options do you have from Maya? XNA supports a few formats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XNA is an interesting platform, but I have noticed it having some performance issues when loading in models.  I have not used WPF to do this, but XNA does also require installing of its framework, to run the application.  I suggest you avoid it, for the hurdles you must jump to get what you want out of it.  DirectX libraries are a good way to accomplish this, there are thousands of examples of this being used out there. [Very Good](http://www.drunkenhyena.com/cgi-bin/dx9_net.pl),[Good](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Visual_Basic/Series1/The_first_triangle.php), [Ok](http://www.euclideanspace.com/software/games/twod/dx9vb/index.htm)

You can also use a .X exporter for Maya to import your models. Something like this [DirectX Maya Exporter](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=383794)